# Excluding higher limit in a probability of density function

Tags: probability

I have this probability of density function (pdf):

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{x}{6} + \frac{1}{12}, & \text{for } 0\le x \le 3, \\ \\0, & \text{for } x < 0 \lor x > 3 \end{cases}$$

$$\\\\\\\\$$

apparently $p(0\le x \le 3) = 1$, but $p(0\le x < 3) = 1$ too. Why does this happen? Shouldn't the sign make a difference?

Comment: What is $p(x=3)$?

Comment: $p(0\leq x\leq 3)=p(0\leq 3< 3)+p(x=3)~~$  What is $p(x=3)$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales $p(x = 3)$ is $\frac{7}{12}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Does that mean that $p(0 \le x < 3) = 1 - \frac{7}{12}$ ?

Comment: No, $f(3)=\frac{7}{12}$, not $p(x=3)$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales how do I find $p(x=3)$?

Comment: The probability density function can only be used to find the probability that $x$ lies in a certain interval or union of intervals. For any constant $c$ in the domain of the density function, $p(x=c)=0$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Ah! Therefore $p(0 \le x < 3) = 1 - p(x = 3) = 1$, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You might be confused by what the PDF represents.  As a probability *density* function of a continuous random variable, $f(x)$ can be thought of, heuristically, as the density of probability *mass* in the vicinity of $x$.  That is to say, the probability of the random variable being within a window of width $\Delta x$, near $x$, is very nearly $f(x) \, \Delta x$, and this approaches equality in the limit, as $\Delta x \to 0$.

By way of analogy, if I were to say that the density of a cable is $2$ g/cc at a point $x = 3$ m from its endpoint, that doesn't mean that the *mass* of the infinitesimally thin slice of cable at $3$ m from the endpoint is $2$ g.  It means that each small section of cable at that location has a density of about $2$ g/cc, so that if you have (let's say) $0.05$ cc of cable, it would have a mass of about $0.1$ g.

In the same way, the random variable $X$ doesn't have a probability of $\frac{7}{12}$ of equalling $3$; it has a probability *density* of $\frac{7}{12}$ at that point.  That is to say, the probability of the random variable falling in the interval $[3-\Delta x, 3]$ is very nearly $\frac{7}{12} \Delta x$, for small $\Delta x$.

One must be careful to distinguish this from a probability mass function of a *discrete* random variable, which *does* give the actual probability of the random variable taking on a given value.  For instance, a geometric random variable $Y$ might have the probability mass function

$$
f_Y(k) = \frac{1}{2^k} \qquad k \geq 1
$$

in which case the probability (*not* the probability density) at $k = 3$ is $P(Y = 3) = \frac{1}{2^3} = \frac{1}{8}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a continuous random variable, then for each $x\in\mathbb R$, we have $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$, as 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=x) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(x-\frac1n\leqslant X \leqslant x+\frac1n \right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{x-\frac1n}^{x+\frac1n} f(t)\ \mathsf dt\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} F\left(x+\frac1n\right) - F\left(x-\frac1n\right)\\
&=0,
\end{align}
since $F$ is continuous (by the fundamental theorem of calculus).

Answer (score 0):

Continuous probability distributions assign probability $0$ to sets containing only one point.  Notice that $\displaystyle \int_a^a f(x)\, dx = 0.$ Apply that when $f$ is a probability density function.